# MenuItem icon is not displaying correctly in RTL Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left, android-menu, optionmenu

In RTL, option menu item icon not displayed correctly!!
but in LTR, everything is displayed well and beautifully.

With the help of this command, I make the RTL program

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

My menu layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_wb_sunny_black_24dp"
                android:title="آیتم شماره 1"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                android:title="آیتم شماره 2"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_wb_sunny_black_24dp"
                android:title="آیتم شماره 3"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Please help me to fix this.

[image]
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTLZ4.png)

Comment: Please post a screenshot to demonstrate what is not displayed correctly.

Comment: sceenshot link added to post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Custom Toolbar popupTheme, override**

`android:layout_marginStart
 android:layout_marginEnd`

**First add this lines to your res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">2dp</item>
</style>
```

**then set Toolbar's popupTheme to 'PopupTheme' as shown above, just like this:**

```
......
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/arrow_back"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/PopupTheme"
    app:title="@string/toolbar_title"/>
......
```

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem in RTL layout, If you are using **Support Library** or **AndroidX** you can apply this easy fix:

1. In you project create new layout file in `res -> layout` with this name `abc_list_menu_item_icon.xml`.
2. Copy the code below to the file in step 1.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!-- Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project

        Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
        you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
        You may obtain a copy of the License at

             http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

        Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
        distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
        WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
        See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
        limitations under the License.
   -->

   <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/icon"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
              android:layout_marginRight="-8dip"
              android:layout_marginStart="8dip"
              android:layout_marginEnd="-8dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
              android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
              android:scaleType="centerInside"
              android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The fix is available in appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02

In changelog :

Support RTL in menu items with icons (I2f5c5):
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1353122

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're using either a vector/xml drawable (i.e. not png), in this case you can use `inset`, specifically `android:insetRight` attribute

You can apply this to all of your drawables: (ic_wb_sunny_black_24dp, ic_star_black_24dp, & ic_wb_sunny_black_24dp)

**Example for vector drawable:**

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetRight="16dp">
    <vector
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24"
        app:tint="@color/item_text">
        <path
            android:fillColor="@color/item_text"
            android:pathData="M22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12M7.4,15.4L12,10.8L16.6,15.4L18,14L12,8L6,14L7.4,15.4Z" />
    </vector>
</inset>
```

**Example for xml drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetRight="16dp">

    <shape android:shape="oval">

        <solid android:color="@color/highlight_1" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/transparent" />
        <size
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="30dp" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create another folder for your language

ex : **layout-ar** for arabic language